# Отрисовка объекта из Класса (и его последующего движения) Python 3 модуля - Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Изучаю python c недавнего времени и модуль Pygame.
  Есть объект (в данном примере Линия). Нужно создать из определенное количество, после чего двигать каждый объект по отдельности куда бы то ни было. В данном случае "от центра".
  Хочу сделать чтобы Класс создавал объект который двигался от центра, а следовательно изменял свои координаты.
  Создать некое количество объектов не проблема, но с их движением все иначе.

Как я это вижу. Идет закрашивание экрана (для обновления и удаления старых рисунков), далее отрисовка объектов с их позициями, но при следующем обновлении (кадре) идет прорисовка заново (Черный экран, и каждый объект создается заново не зная свою позицию, а беря ее из списка). Это то как, получилось пока.

```
import pygame
from random import*

top, side = (0, 0)
FPS = 144
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width = 640
height = 360
amount = 100
num = []
conditions = [(-10, -10), (width + 10, height + 10),
              (width + 10, -10), (-10, height + 10)]
c = conditions
for i in range(amount):
    num.append((randint(0, width), randint(0, height)))

def check(num):
    global top, side
    x, y = num
    minus, plus = (-1, 1)
    if   x <= width / 2 and y <= height / 2:
        side, top = (minus, minus)
    elif x >= width / 2 and y <= height / 2:
        side, top = (plus, minus)
    elif x <= width / 2 and y >= height / 2:
        side, top = (minus, plus)
    elif x >= width / 2 and y >= height / 2:
        side, top = (plus, plus)
    elif x == width / 2 and y == height / 2:
        side, top = (plus, plus)

class star:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.x, self.y = num
        self.check()
        pygame.draw.aaline(win, (255, 0, 0),
             [self.x, self.y], [self.x + self.sx, self.y + self.sy])

    def check(self):
        self.minus, self.plus = (-1, 1)
        if self.x <= width / 2:
            self.sx = -10
            self.side = self.minus
        else:
            self.sx = 10
            self.side = self.plus
        if self.y <= height / 2:
            self.sy = -10
            self.top = self.minus
        else:
            self.sy = 10
            self.top = self.plus

#pygame.draw.aaline(win, (255, 0, 0), [10, 70], [290, 55])

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: run = False
#------Draw----------------
    for i in range(amount):
        check(num[i])
        num[i] = (num[i][0] + (side), num[i][1] + (top))
    for i in range(amount):
        n = num[i]
        star(n)
        if n <= c[0] or n >= c[1] or n >= c[2] or n <= c[3] or n == (width / 2, height / 2):
            num[i] = (randint(0, width), randint(0, height))

#------------------------

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Хотелось бы чтобы объект(Класс) сам помнил свою позицию и двигался от центра.
  Есть ли возможность это написать, как то компактнее и понятнее?

Как то непонятно описал. Если добавлю несколько объектов в область --Draw--

```
#------Draw----------------
        for i in range(amount):
            check(num[i])
            num[i] = (num[i][0] + (side), num[i][1] + (top))
        for i in range(amount):
            n = num[i]
            star(n)
            if n <= c[0] or n >= c[1] or n >= c[2] or n <= c[3] or n == (width / 2, height / 2):
                num[i] = (randint(0, width), randint(0, height))

    #------------------------

        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
```

То они нарисуются в разных местах и как надо, а если захочу до черного экрана, чтобы присвоить их к чему-то и как хранить?

@virvaldium, спасибо за помощь. На основе ваших примеров сделал такой код:

```
import pygame
from random import*

FPS = 60
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
width = 640
height = 360
amount = 100

class GameManager:
    def __init__(self, game_window, array):
        self.game_window = game_window
        self.array = array

    def redraw(self):
        self.game_window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for star in self.array:
            star.set_new_position()

class Star:
    def __init__(self, game_window, start_x, start_y):
        self.x = start_x
        self.y = start_y
        self.game_window = game_window
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.game_window, (255, 0, 0),
                          [self.x, self.y], 3)

    def set_new_position(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 1
        self.draw()

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

array = [Star(win, randint(0, width),
                        randint(0, height)) for i in range(amount)]

manager = GameManager(win, array)
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    manager.redraw()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Разбирался долго, зато понял). Создать количество теперь можно и задать им действия тоже не проблема, дело за малым)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно... 
Если я правильно понял суть написанного, то необходимо сделать как-то так, что бы объекты порожденные от класса Star самостоятельно двигались от центра к краям экрана? То есть звездочки у Вас будут летать по экрану.

На мой взгляд в Вашем коде проблема в большей степени архитектурная. Я бы на вашем месте придумал бы какой-нибудь менеджер, который бы управлял перерисовкой игрового поля. Предупреждаю сразу - я с pygame работал очень давно, так что на истинность кода не претендую, тут я показываю только концепцию.
Выглядело бы это примерно так:

```
class GameManager:
    def __init__(self, game_window, star_array):
        self.game_window = game_window  # содержит ссылку на игровое поле
        self.star_array = star_array    # список всех звезд, которыми нужно управлять

    def redraw(self):
        self.game_window.fill((0, 0, 0))  # закрашиваем поле в черный цвет
        for star in self.star_array:
            star.set_new_position()   # перерисовываем позиции звезд
```

класс Star выглядел бы при этом как-то так:

```
class Star:
    def __init__(self, game_window, start_x, start_y):
            self.x = start_x
        self.y = start_y
        self.game_window = game_window
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        # тут логика отрисовки объекта на self.game_window по координатам self.x и self.y
        pass

    def set_new_position(self):
        # тут будут задаваться новые координаты и после вызываться метод self.draw()
        pass
```

Старт программы бы выглядел как-то так:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

    start_array = [star for star in Star(win, randint(0, 10), randint(0, 10))]

    manager = GameManager(win, star_array)
    while True:
        manager.redraw()
```

Я надеюсь, что Вы понимаете  - это просто концепция, того как бы сделал это я. В случае с Вашим подходом... Наверное можно было бы в начале каждого цикла перекрашивать поле в черный цвет:

```
for i in range(amount):
        win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))  # <<<<< добавить какую-то такую строчку, или как там в pygame задается цвет игрового поля...
        n = num[i]
        star(n)
        if n <= c[0] or n >= c[1] or n >= c[2] or n <= c[3] or n == (width / 2, height / 2):
            num[i] = (randint(0, width), randint(0, height))
```

но такой подход, когда пересоздаются объекты класса Star, выглядит, на мой взгляд, несколько не оптимальным и запутанным. Инициализация объекта достаточно долгая операция, плюс каждый раз будет заниматься дополнительная область в памяти (когда там ее сборщик мусора обработает...). А если потребуется изменить механизм полета звезд? А если потребуется, что бы одни звезды летали по кругу, а не от центра к краю? А когда дело дойдет до взаимодействия с игроком? - тут перерисовку звезд придется учитывать с тем объектом, которым управляет игрок.

Повторюсь еще раз, с библиотекой pygame я работал мало и давно. В своем ответе показываю только концептуальный подход к поставленной задаче

**P.S.**
Ну и плюсом... Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал:

1. перестать использовать глобальные переменные для обмена данными -
   это зло во плоти.
2. почитать PEP8
3. почитать как работает типизация в питоне и чем отличаются изменяемы
   и не изменяемы типы данных друг от друга:

conditions = [(-10, -10), (width + 10, height + 10), (width + 10, -10), (-10, height + 10)]

c = conditions

Зачем Вы делаете две ссылки на один и тот же массив? с и conditions будут оперировать одним и тем же списком и изменять его мешая работе друг друга. Такие баги очень сложно отыскивать. Если хотите, скопировать один list в другой, то почитайте про функции copy и deepcopy из стандартного модуля copy

Comment: Мой код запутан и местами усложнен, так как мало знаний, conditions присвоил для уменьшения длины имени (возможно не верно, не отрицаю).

Comment: Поэтому и спрашиваю, как бы сделал другой). Сейчас пытаюсь сделать многослойную прорисовку, как бы создавая группами звёзды и по истечении времени или достижения определенной величины появлялся бы второй слой

Comment: а как можно было бы избежать пересоздание класса?
 Я как раз и хочу этого избежать, хотелось бы их просто создать определенным количеством, а после манипулировать.
Понял пример сверху, пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Использовать тот вариант, который я описал. В нем Вы в самом начале создаете массив звезд, а потом в цикле стираете их на поле и проприсовываете